# Binding dynamic datalist in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datalist

I am trying to create a dynamic Data List bind with database. I can easily create this but I am not able to make the item Command of this Data List. Please help me. Here is my code below

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            categorybinding();
        }
    }

    public void categorybinding()
    {
        int totalcate = (from x in ebooks.books_category select x).Count();

        var ra = (from x in ebooks.books_category select x);

        DataList dl = new DataList();
        dl.ItemTemplate = new DatalistLabelColumnBind();
        dl.DataSource = ra;
        dl.DataBind();

        form1.Controls.Add(dl);
        dl.ItemCommand += new DataListCommandEventHandler(this.ItemCommandHandler);

    }

    public void ItemCommandHandler(object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("NewPage.aspx?"+e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    }


//Create a new class implementing ITemplate
public class DatalistLabelColumnBind : ITemplate
{
    public DatalistLabelColumnBind()
    {
        //Add constructor 
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        LinkButton label1 = new LinkButton();
        label1.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.BindLabelColumn);
        container.Controls.Add(label1);
    }
    public void BindLabelColumn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        LinkButton lbl = (LinkButton)sender;
        DataListItem  container = (DataListItem)lbl.NamingContainer ;
        String strVals = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(((DataListItem)container).DataItem, "books_category1"));
        lbl.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(((DataListItem)container).DataItem, "id_books"));
        lbl.Text = strVals;
    }
}
```

My Problem :

1. My Data List easily added on the page but when I click on the Link Button which is added in the Data List is does not Redirect to the NewPage.aspx

Help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `categorybinding()` function after the if condition in `Page_Load`. And `ItemCommandHandler` will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Response.Redirect is not resolving to the intended page.

Try:

```
Response.Redirect("~/NewPage.aspx?"+e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

Comment: Did you also try Response.Redirect("/NewPage.aspx?"+e.CommandArgument.ToString()); If that does not work then set a break point on the handler and see if it stops there. If not you may want to add the handler before form1.Controls.Add(dl);

Comment: I set the break point on the handler, yes its stop there. Now what should i do ?
And i add the handler before form1.Contols.Add(dl); but this does not work