# DataList Command cannot redirect to another page

Tags: c#, webforms, datalist

I'm facing a problem that I can't redirect to another page by using DataList Command. Here is my code for aspx.

```
<asp:DataList id="CategoryList"
       OnItemCommand="Barcode_RowCommand"
       BorderColor="black"
       CellPadding="1"
       CellSpacing="1"
       RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
       RepeatLayout="Table"
       RepeatColumns="4"
       BorderWidth="0"
       runat="server" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Font-Names="arial" ItemStyle-Font-Size="12px"                   
       ItemStyle-ForeColor="#ffffff" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
```

How i handle the command with a image button

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Add" 
          ImageUrl= '<%# "getImage.aspx?Barcode=" + Eval("Barcode")  %>'
          ForeColor="black" 
          runat="server"
          Visible="true"
          Width = "200px"
          height ="170px"
          CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Barcode")%>'
          DataKeyField="Barcode"
          CommandName="Add"></asp:ImageButton>
```

below is my code for aspx.cs

```
public void Barcode_RowCommand(Object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Add")
        {
            Response.Redirect("ProductDetail.aspx");
        }
    }
```

the code has no error but when i click on the image button, it doesn't redirect me to the productdtail.aspx but just at the same page. any help or suggestion will be appreciate. thanks again

Comment: 1.  What is the page_load code for product details? Did you put break point at if block of event handler? Are response.redirect line getting executed?

Comment: Put a break point  and Check the given path in  Response.Redirect.

Comment: @SatyakiChatterjee i didn't put any code for product details yet, i will put the break point and see

Comment: thanks for your time @SatyakiChatterjee, i solved my issue.

Comment: and not to forget @rajeeshmenoth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as my issue i just do some changes to the following code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.ViewState["vs"] = 0;
            pos = (int)this.ViewState["vs"];

            databind2();
            databind();
        }   
    }
```

at first my databind2 and databind were out of the if statement and i follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22767907/5466000) and put my databind2 and databind into if statement and my problem solved. thanks for your time